# How to get a standard JavaScript File API object using the Windows.Storage FileOpenPicker class?

Tags: javascript, windows-8, winjs, fileapi, storagefile

While working on a  Windows 8 app, I noticed that I can open and get a reference to a File object using something like:

```
// Markup
<input type='file' id='myfile'/>

// JavaScript
var fInput = document.getElementById('myFile');
fInput.onchange = function (e) {
    var dataSource = e.target;
    var file = dataSource.files[0]; // object of type 'File'
}
```

However I would like to present the user with a file picker without the need to press the 'Browse' button. So I tried using the FilePicker class like this:

```
var picker = new Windows.Storage.Pickers.FileOpenPicker();
picker.pickSingleFileAsync().then(function (file) {
    // in this case, file is a 'StorageFile' object
});
```

So the question is, can `pickSingleFileAsync` somehow return a `File` object instead of `StorageFile` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [MSApp.createFileFromStorageFile](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/Hh831249.aspx).  Ignore the documentation error here. It tells the reverse of what the api does.

```
// TODO - more code is required here to initialize file open picker. 
// refer the file picker sample
var picker = new Windows.Storage.Pickers.FileOpenPicker();
picker.pickSingleFileAsync().then(function (storageFile) {
    // ignore when file pick is cancelled
    if (!storageFile)
        return;
    var file = MSApp.createFileFromStorageFile(storageFile);
});
```